# RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (32x16384 and 50176x4096)

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, computer-vision

This was my code in the beginning where image size is 448,448. This was working well.

```
def _create_fcs(self, split_size, num_boxes, num_classes):
    S, B, C = split_size, num_boxes, num_classes
    return nn.Sequential(nn.Flatten(), nn.Linear(1024 * S * S, 4096), nn.Dropout(0.0), nn.LeakyReLU(0.1), nn.Linear(4096, S * S * (C + B * 5)))
```

This is my changed version with image size 224,224. The error occured when this block was entered.

```
def _create_fcs(self, split_size, num_boxes, num_classes):
      S,B,C = split_size, num_boxes, num_classes
      return nn.Sequential(nn.Flatten(), nn.Linear(1024 * S * S, 4096))
```

I was implementing YOLOv1 as mentioned in the research paper. while trying to use the model trained in image size 224,224 to the model trained in 448,448. I am getting this error

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (32x16384 and 50176x4096)

Comment: What's the full stack trace?